# JUnit 5 + Apache Surefire Plugin - How to use custom listener

Tags: junit, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm taking my first steps into testing, so don't be strict.

How I can use my custom listener in JUnit 5, if I use Apache Surefire Plugin for running my tests? It TestNG it is easy because I can use annotation `@Listeners` or write my listener in .xml with the suite of tests. It JUnit I can't find working decision.

My custom listener:

```
public class OnrTestListener implements TestExecutionListener {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getRootLogger();

    @Override
    public void executionSkipped(TestIdentifier testIdentifier, String reason) {
        LOG.info("SKIPPED Test by reason: {}", reason);
    }

    @Override
    public void executionStarted(TestIdentifier testIdentifier) {
        LOG.info("Test {} successfully started.", testIdentifier.getDisplayName());
    }

    @Override
    public void executionFinished(TestIdentifier testIdentifier, TestExecutionResult testExecutionResult) {
        if (testExecutionResult.getStatus() != TestExecutionResult.Status.SUCCESSFUL) {
            String message = "Page screenshot.";
            File screenshot = ScreenshotUtils.takeScreenshot();
            ScreenshotUtils.attachToReportPortal(message, screenshot);
        }
    }
```

My additional class ScreenshotUtils

```
public class ScreenshotUtils {

    private static final OnrLogger LOG = new OnrLogger();

    private ScreenshotUtils() {
    }

    public static void attachToReportPortal(String message, File screenshot) {
        ReportPortal.emitLog(message, "info", new Date(), screenshot);
    }

    public static File takeScreenshot() {
        return ((TakesScreenshot) DriverFactory.getDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    }
}
```

My tests marked some annotations (because I can't find some decision for making suite) and run my tests like:

```
mvn clean test -Dgroups=some_tag
```

How I tried to use my listener:

1. I tried to use annotation:

   @ExtendWith(OnrTestListener.class)
   @Tag("all")
   public abstract class BaseUITest {
   ...
   }
2. Using config in surefire plugin

   ```
                 <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>com.google.listeners.OnrTestListener</value>
                        </property>
                        <configurationParameters>
                            junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled = true
                            junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true
                            junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = concurrent
                            junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default = concurrent
                            junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.strategy = fixed
                            junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism = 5
                        </configurationParameters>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
   ```

But it doesn't work.

I would be grateful for any help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SPI mechanism.

Add a file `org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener` to the `/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/` folder.

Then add the full name of your listener `{your package}.OnrTestListener` to this file.

The listener will be applied automatically.